# C Linux shell - repeat the recent commands

Tags: c, linux, shell, command, history

I'm trying to implement a linux shell and in this part I'm trying to repeat the recent used commands. Here a sample from the code

```
if(strcmp(arg[0],"!") == 0 && arg[1] != NULL){
            if(strcmp(arg[1], "-1") == 0){
                 system("!!");


            }
```

I want the last command to execute when the user enters "! -1" I tried the system command "!!" but i got an error "command not found". Can you help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OP, you have asked the same question 2 or 3 times in varying ways. Think it through.  You are writing a shell.  You have your own command line through which users enter commands.  You are trying to *mimic* what bash does not *use* bash.  How would you store and retrieve the command lines your users enter?  Is writing to a file required or is just storing them in some kind of data structure you can search and access during the running of your pgm (shell) sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `!!` is not really a command. It is a shortcut in bash to repeat the last recently used command. What's happening is that `system` is looking for `!!` binary file in your `PATH` environment variable and of course, failing to find it.

What you can do is what most shells do, keep a file of last used commands and execute the last one issued.

For example, take a look at the file `~/.bash_history`. That's the command history the console keeps track of for your user. In order to achieve what you want either you store the commands in a buffer in memory (not a very good idea because if you reset or close the shell you'll lose the history) or have them in a `.bash_history`-like file.

Also, take a look at the `history` command and mostly its manual page (`man history`). You'll find a section `PROGRAMMING WITH HISTORY FUNCTIONS` that you might find useful. By including `<readline/history.h>` you'll get access to some functions that operates on the history. I don't know if you can use it, because this might be only accessible within `bash` and since you're creating your own shell, maybe it won't work. I still think that keeping track of the history yourself is a way of [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 but my guess OP doesn't anything that elaborate.  Normally assignments just request they save N past commands in memory somewhere and call them up on request.

Comment: I concur. I made the _keep in memory suggestion_ for that reason. The point of my answer was to point the OP why he was getting the error and made a suggestion on a possible solution